# Add "field" to customized Beamer theme

Tags: beamer, themes

I'm working on a beamer theme custom tailored to my needs. Now I need to introduce a custom field or tag `\MYTAG`, similar to `\frametitle` that holds certain information and may be retrieved in the .sty-files via `\insertMYTAG`, again like `\insertframetitle`. I tried to mimick it but failed utterly. I would use it like in the following excerpt from my `beamerouterthemeMYTHEME.sty`

```
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{MYTHEME theme}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}
    \insertframenumber\hskip1em \insertframetitle \insertMYTAG%
    \usebeamerfont{headline}%
    \vskip.5ex  
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

Can anyone give me a hint on how and where to define this tag?

Comment: tnx Stefan for inline highlighting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beamer has the original definitions for the different `\insert`-commands in the file `beamerbasetitle.sty`. This is the definition for the date command for example:

```
%
%
% The \date command
%
%
\def\date{\@dblarg\beamer@date}
\long\def\beamer@date[#1]#2{%
  \def\insertdate{#2}%
  \def\beamer@shortdate{#1}%
  }
\date{\today}


\newcommand\insertshortdate[1][]{%
  {%
    \let\thanks=\@gobble%
    \beamer@setupshort{#1}%
    \beamer@insertshort{\beamer@shortdate}%
  }}
```

For your needs you can use:

```
%
%
% The \MYTAG command
%
%
\newcommand{\MYTAG}{\@dblarg\beamer@MYTAG}
\long\def\beamer@MYTAG[#1]#2{%
  \def\insertMYTAG{#2}  %
  \def\insertshortMYTAG{#1}%
  }
\MYTAG[defaultShortMYTAG]{defaultLongMYTAG}
```

which will work analogously to `\author[]{}`, `\date[]{}`, `\institute[]{}` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need to define this command in the same file (i.e. `beamerbasetitle.sty`) or can I do this in my `beamerthemeMYTHEME.sty`? If I do the latter I get an `! Undefined control sequence` on the line making the call with the default values (last line in your example).

Comment: Dooh, stupid me. Seems like I misinterpreted the error message. I defined the command AFTER defining the outertheme which uses the `\insertMYTAG` command. Moving the definition up, it works now. Big thanks!

Comment: Feels like it shouldn't matter where in your .sty file you put the definition. 
You need to have in in the .sty file or in your preamble surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` though. Anyhow, I'm glad it's of use to you! I spent quite some time understanding how beamer does this when I was creating a theme of my own.. `:)`